# Mesh moves when trying to attach weights

Tags: vertex-weights

My mesh moves from the armature when I try to add weights. I followed the answers in another thread where it said to apply rotation loc and scale to mesh and armature which I did plus tried merge by distance, but the problem is still the same :/. Anyone know why?

Also the eyes and the teeth are separate object. How do I make sure they follow the head as it moves later on? Do I have to add them to the rig too? And how do I do that?

My blender file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1i6xRZwlATJJtPr6VQTGiB3muerGI0zv6

Hopefully someone not as new to this as me can help me :/

Respectfully, Ellen

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: The problem is the mesh has a parent called goat_obj_root.001, which has transforms. Apply the transforms on that empty, then try again.

Comment: Oh it worked! Thanks! Do I have to add the weights with the eyes and the teeth on shift at the same time or should I just pick the body mesh and the bones and add weights?

Comment: It doesn't count. You can do it in the same time or individually.

Comment: Ok because if I do it at the same time and then go into Pose mode and adjust the model the teeth and the eyes pop out of the model and goes elsewhere. Do you know how I can adjust so they follow the head? Is it the Keep offset thing?

Comment: No, that's because the automatic weights are wrong, you have to repaint the head's weight in weight paint mode or reassign the vertex group in edit mode. But if there are no bones to open the mouth, why don't you delete the teeth?

Comment: Oooh ok I see! Ill remove the teeth and then hit up a tutorial on weight painting, thanks so much, you helped a lot! Hope I can pay back to the community as I get better at this

Comment: I tend to make a non-deforming bone for the eyes and teeth, and parent them to it. Teeth, after all, should stay rigid, and eyes should keep their shape. Unless of course you're doing a really cartoony rig.